# How to detect why a computer has WPF automation peers activated?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ui-automation, automationpeer

Our application is crashing on some computers because they have some software activating the WPF automation peers. Is there a way to know which application is activating them?

We have a stack trace that shows the following code:

```
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 54 + 0x16 bytes  C#
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CatchException(System.Exception e) Line 2978    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CatchExceptionStatic(object source, System.Exception e) Line 2962 + 0x9 bytes   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.CatchException(object source, System.Exception e, System.Delegate catchHandler) Line 177 + 0xd bytes  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Line 43 + 0x17 bytes    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) Line 1447 + 0x2d bytes    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Line 398 Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    UIAutomationTypes.dll!System.Windows.Automation.AutomationIdentifier.Register(MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreTypesApi.AutomationIdType type, System.Guid guid, string programmaticName) + 0x31 bytes 
    UIAutomationTypes.dll!System.Windows.Automation.InvokePatternIdentifiers.InvokePatternIdentifiers() + 0x4b bytes    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.Initialize() Line 1840 + 0x28 bytes Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.AutomationPeer() Line 278 + 0x5 bytes   Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.RaiseFocusChangedEventHelper(System.Windows.IInputElement newFocus) Line 387    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(System.Windows.DependencyObject focus, int timestamp) Line 565 + 0x17 bytes    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(System.Windows.DependencyObject newFocus, System.Windows.Input.IKeyboardInputProvider keyboardInputProvider, bool askOld, bool askNew, bool forceToNullIfFailed) Line 443 + 0xc bytes   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.DependencyObject focus, bool askOld, bool askNew, bool forceToNullIfFailed) Line 220 + 0x19 bytes Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.IInputElement element) Line 181   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.OnSetFocus(System.IntPtr hwnd) Line 558   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage message, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Line 379   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Line 1757 + 0x1b bytes Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Line 345 + 0x16 bytes   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Line 494 + 0x18 bytes   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) Line 111 + 0xa bytes Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Line 41 + 0x17 bytes    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) Line 1447 + 0x2d bytes    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Line 398 Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Line 672 + 0x29 bytes  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Line 424 + 0x1a bytes    Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(object booleanBox) + 0x120 bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.Show() + 0x5c bytes 
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog() + 0x27d bytes
```

You can see in the middle of the callstack the automation API firing. On most machines this does not happen and the app works fine.

We could address the real issue but given that this happens on a very small set of machines I think it will be faster to stop the application enabling the automation subsystem.

Comment: Are you looking for AutomationInteropProvider.ClientsAreListening? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.provider.automationinteropprovider.clientsarelistening.aspx one way to solve this is also to override `OnCreateAutomationPeer` on proper controls or child controls to make sure nothing funky's indirectly triggered by the listeners.

Comment: @SimonMourier: thanks, its close but I was looking for the list of applications so I can uninstall / stop them.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.